# VBA Macro for Textbox Timer

Tags: excel, vba

Cell A1 contains specific fixed Date and Time.

I want to show elapsed time in TextBox in same sheet in mm:ss format.

for e.g A1= "2023-04-07 13:05:10"

and current system time is "2023-04-07 13:30:16"

Then Textbox should show "25m 05s"
and this should refresh every second (increase) until A1 is blank.

Basically it  is elapsed timer

Answer (score 0):

The code must be in a module (not in a sheet module). If the value of A1 can take wrong values then you can also uncomment the On Error commands... The codename of the sheet is SHEET1 which you will change with the real name of your own sheet

```
Public Sub elapsed_timer()
   Dim v As Double, s As String
   s = SHEET1.Range("A1").Value
   If (s = "") Then Exit Sub
   Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "elapsed_timer"
   'On Error Resume Next
   v = Now() - (DateValue(s) + TimeValue(s))
   'On Error GoTo 0
   SHEET1.TextBox1.Value = Format(v, "mm") & "m " & Format(v, "ss") & "s"
End Sub
```